# Order by sum(value) sql

Tags: mysql, sum, sql-order-by

I am trying to get a list of blog_id and the sum of donations on that blog id from a table called donations. And I want to order it by the sum of donations. Basically I want to produce a list of blogs ranked by donations. Blogs are held in a different table referenced by blog_id.

This is what I have been trying but all it does is sum up all donations and produce 1 row. I don't understand what I did wrong here!

```
$donations_result = mysql_query("SELECT blog_id, sum(amount) FROM donations ORDER BY sum(amount)");
```

Donations table is a series of blog_ids and individual donations. So something like this:

blog_id--donation
1 ----------26
1 ----------1
2 ----------24
2 ----------12

Comment: A group by clause should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not group the columns. You need to group it by non-aggregated column and in this case by `blog_id`

```
SELECT blog_id, sum(amount) TotalSum
FROM   donations 
GROUP  BY blog_id
ORDER  BY TotalSum
```

The reason why your query executed well without throwing an exception is because mysql permits to use *aggregate function* without specifying non-aggregated column in the `GROUP BY` clause.

- [see MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: Great minds think alike! JW answered first, so give him the credit!

Comment: Oh that is why then. I thought it was unusual for sql to do something that I wasn't planning without spitting it out....

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `GROUP BY` operator:

```
SELECT   blog_id, sum(amount) 
FROM     donations
GROUP BY blog_id
ORDER BY sum(amount)
```

Comment: worked thanks. And ty to everyone else too! Ticks for everyone :D